# NUnit Test Cases Input Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, nunit

My code takes input from file. If i have to write NUnit test case for it, do i have to change my code and take input from test case instead of file or is it possible that i don't have to change my code.?

Help Please.

Given below is one of the functions which i have to test.

```
    public void CLEAN_Discipline(string disp)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////SQL CONNECTION////////////////////////////////////////////////

        string sqlconnectionString = "server=localhost;" + "database=fastdata;" + "uid=dwh;" + "password=dwh;";
        MySqlConnection cnMySQL = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmdMySQL = cnMySQL.CreateCommand();
        cmdMySQL.CommandText = "Select * from single";
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        String query;
        MySqlCommand cmd2;
        cnMySQL.Open();
        reader = cmdMySQL.ExecuteReader(); 


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string disp = reader["Discipline"].ToString();

            disp = disp.ToUpper();
            disp = disp.Replace("MS", "");
            disp = disp.Replace("-", "");
            disp = disp.Replace(" ", "");

            string roll = reader["RollNumber"].ToString();


            MySqlConnection cnMySQL2 = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnectionString);
            cnMySQL2.Open();
            query = "UPDATE single SET Discipline = ('" + disp + "')  where RollNumber = '" + roll + "' ";
            cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, cnMySQL2);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnMySQL2.Close();
        }
        cnMySQL.Close();

        cnMySQL.Open();
        reader = cmdMySQL.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string roll = reader["RollNumber"].ToString();
            string disp = reader["Discipline"].ToString();
            string degree = reader["Degree"].ToString();
            if (degree == "MS")
            {
                if (roll[0] == 'I')
                {
                    if (disp != "CS" && disp != "SPM" && disp != "")
                    {
                        disp = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                }
                else if (roll[0] == 'K')
                {
                    if (disp != "CS" && disp != "SPM" && disp != "TC" && disp != "NW")
                    {
                        disp = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                }
                else if (roll[0] == 'P')
                {
                    if (disp != "CS" && disp != "TC")
                    {
                        disp = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                }
                else if (roll[0] == 'L')
                {
                    if (disp != "CS" && disp != "SPM" && disp != "TC" && disp != "NW")
                    {
                        disp = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                }
            }
            if (disp == "UNKNOWN")
            {
                MySqlConnection cnMySQL2 = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnectionString);
                cnMySQL2.Open();
                query = "UPDATE single SET Discipline = ('" + disp + "')  where RollNumber = '" + roll + "' ";
                cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, cnMySQL2);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnMySQL2.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to break up your function into smaller functions so you can test just the parts containing logic.

In your case perhaps you should extract the logic that replaces aspects of the string you want to check into a function that takes a string. You can then test that function without all the other dependencies (reading and writing for the database).

[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) by Michael Feathers is a great resource for explaining how to create seams in your code that allow for testing.

Comment: Is it possible that i don't break up my function and still test it? without changing the file input.